# How to create a Ms Access Database from multiple excel sheets which has multi-row in each?

Tags: excel, ms-access

I'm a newbie in creating Access database. My data has *300 rows * 10 columns* in each and every excel sheet. Excel sheet differs to every shipment. Now, how should I make my MS table according to this. How to make 1 table contain all the shipment details, which means *300 rows * 10 columns * 100 shipments*?

Comment: You need to read up on database normalization. Rather than 1 single table, you will need to have different tables for the different objects (such as customers, products) and also junction tables (products ordered by customers).

Comment: The objects are not like you've mentioned, the objects are type1,type2,type3,...( the contents per box). So, sometimes I have 18 types go in to 1 box, and I'll have 18 columns * 300 rows. And I have to come up with 18 different tables in ER diagram? How can I simplify this step? Thanks for your assistance.

Comment: As it stands, your question is not suitable for this SO. You will need to concentrate on getting the database design right before you actually open up MS Access. You will probably need to have a table for "Type" (fields such as TypeID, TypeName), a table for Boxes (BoxID, BoxName), and a junction table called BoxType (BoxTypeID, BoxID, TypeID, Qty).